# PayPal express checkout: how should I check if the transaction is done and money is transferred?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, spree-paypal-express

I have PayPal express checkout on the client side and after the callback is fired with payment ID I want to check that id on the NodeJS side. I make a call to RESTfull API using JS SDK:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/v1/#payment_get

and I get such object below.

**state is approved** but `transactions[0].related_resources[0].sale.state` === **pending**

So how should I check if the transaction is done and money is transferred to the seller to activate the service he/she paid for?

from the callback, I have buyer email, payerId, paymentID, paymentToken so maybe I need some other endpoint?

```
{
            "id": "PAY-7SN4959762125513LLPOWTDA",
            "intent": "sale",
            "state": "approved",
            "cart": "2A9434180T1061602",
            "payer": {
                "payment_method": "paypal",
                "status": "VERIFIED",
                "payer_info": {
                    "email": "pp-test@gmail.com",
                    "first_name": "Some",
                    "last_name": "Surname",
                    "payer_id": "E76V3DRUQZYZW",
                    "shipping_address": {
                        "recipient_name": "Some Surname"
                    },
                    "phone": "0455346902",
                    "country_code": "FR"
                }
            },
            "transactions": [
                {
                    "amount": {
                        "total": "27.96",
                        "currency": "EUR",
                        "details": {
                            "subtotal": "27.96"
                        }
                    },
                    "payee": {
                        "merchant_id": "FJ96CP2E7QWMY"
                    },
                    "description": "The payment for services.",
                    "custom": "ws-1XWCLNRbVdWavMVZgH2cSE",
                    "invoice_number": "in-1h7KSgdCh35Gdpi_Yk7PO_",
                    "item_list": {
                        "items": [],
                        "shipping_address": {
                            "recipient_name": "Some Surname"
                        }
                    },
                    "related_resources": [
                        {
                            "sale": {
                                "id": "7UB08136N5814360K",
                                "state": "pending",
                                "amount": {
                                    "total": "27.96",
                                    "currency": "EUR",
                                    "details": {
                                        "subtotal": "27.96"
                                    }
                                },
                                "payment_mode": "INSTANT_TRANSFER",
                                "reason_code": "RECEIVING_PREFERENCE_MANDATES_MANUAL_ACTION",
                                "protection_eligibility": "ELIGIBLE",
                                "protection_eligibility_type": "ITEM_NOT_RECEIVED_ELIGIBLE,UNAUTHORIZED_PAYMENT_ELIGIBLE",
                                "parent_payment": "PAY-7SN4959762125513LLPOWTDA",
                                "create_time": "2018-11-03T09:25:53Z",
                                "update_time": "2018-11-03T09:25:53Z",
                                "links": [
                                    {
                                        "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/sale/7UB08136N5814360K",
                                        "rel": "self",
                                        "method": "GET"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/sale/7UB08136N5814360K/refund",
                                        "rel": "refund",
                                        "method": "POST"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-7SN4959762125513LLPOWTDA",
                                        "rel": "parent_payment",
                                        "method": "GET"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "create_time": "2018-11-03T09:25:32Z",
            "links": [
                {
                    "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-7SN4959762125513LLPOWTDA",
                    "rel": "self",
                    "method": "GET"
                }
            ],
            "httpStatusCode": 200
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what I finally found out:

> The "approved" state just means the buyer logged into their account
>   and approved the payment.  You still need to execute the payment
>   request, which once you do check the "state" shown in the
>   "related_resources" section and it should say "completed", which
>   indicates the transaction amount has been captured.  The "id" shown
>   below is the transaction identifier.

https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/REST-APIs/IPN-vs-actions-payment-execute-result/td-p/1564037

Answer (score 0):

```
<PayPalButtons
        createOrder = {async(data, actions) => {
            return actions.order.create({
                purchase_units: [
                    {
                      
                        amount: {
                            value:'value',
                        },
                    },
                ],
            });
        }}

        onApprove = {async (data, actions) => {
            //Ignore Capture on Client side and do it on server
            //Send Data to Server (mostly data.orderId and data.accessToken)
        }}
    />


// Backend
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
// capture Function
const capturePayment = async (orderId, accessToken) => { //orderId and accessToken from frontend
  
   const url = 'https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/${orderId}/capture';
   const response = await fetch(url,{
      method:"post",
      headers: {
         "Content-Type": "application/json",
         Authorization:`Bearer ${accessToken}`, 
      },
   });
   const data = await response.json();
   console.log(data)
   return data;
}
```